# How to install Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine?

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I tried to install Ubuntu on a machine having Windows OS.While installing Ubuntu I was not able to see all the partitions and I had to format the hard drive. Now the result is that I am having the clean Hard Drive with no primary partition and I am not able to install Windows OS also.

Please suggest me some steps to how can I install Windows OS and Ubuntu on the same machine?Also suggest me steps to create primary partition.

I googled but while following the steps got messed up.Please suggest me some links.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But I am not able to boot windows.So I can't follow that post.I previously read many post what you suggested.I need a solution Which tells **How to create primary partition** Then **How to install windows such that ubuntu can also be installed**

Comment: read this article [HowTo Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

Comment: If you did format your hard drive what was unnecessary but if you  did you have to create new partition table, Windows uses NTFS commonly and Ubuntu uses EXT4 nowadays.

Comment: Thanks @JohnyD. But can you suggest me how to proceed.Yes I read some suggesion in that it is mentioned to create separate partition .

Comment: if you want to install Windows and Ubuntu on the same machine firstly you need to install Windows because Windows don't wanna see any other OS's installed on Hard Drive. To find out of the first steps and how to install Windows you can find on its [official website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1) and ways of installing Ubuntu including dual-boot over [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) what partitions do you need for Ubuntu and sharing with other OS's I've already provided in upper comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fix boot**
After installing ubuntu the default boot will be GRUB so you need to replace it with MBR and below is how to fix it

1- boot from windows 7 or XP CD.
2- select repair --> cmd prompt.
3- input `bootRec.exe /fixmbr`

**then you can install windows without any problem**

**Dual boot windows and ubuntu**

please check the below URL

[UBUNTU Wubi installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi)